# change fontweight inside of section in moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I'd like to change the font weight inside of the section, but now I need to add `\textbf{}` in all of them. Is there a easier way to achieve this for the whole document?

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper, sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[scale=0.85, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.6cm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[11pt]{moresize}

\firstname{First}
\familyname{Last}
\email{email@gmail.com}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}

\section{\textbf{Awards}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to add command `\textbf` into the style definition like:

```
\renewcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\sectionfont\textcolor{color1}{\textbf{#1}}}}
%                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The following complete MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper, sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[scale=0.85, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.6cm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[11pt]{moresize}

\firstname{First}
\familyname{Last}
\email{email@gmail.com}

\renewcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\sectionfont\textcolor{color1}{\textbf{#1}}}}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}

\section{Awards}

\end{document}
```

with the wished result:

[image: resulting pdf]